# Why are all HTML form fields disabled except for buttons?

Tags: angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

The following HTML is pretty straight forward but is not working correctly. I cannot for the life of me see what is causing this. Although there is a JS module, even when I comment out the functionality, this behavior occurs. It is not a CSS issue. There are no console errors.
The project includes bootstrap and angular but they are not used in this form

The [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h536qw9m/1/)

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Writer's Tryst - Manage Uploads</title>
            table { 
                border-spacing:0;
                border-collapse:collapse;
            }
            td, th {
                padding: 5px;
            }
            .nbr-pages {
                width:  48px;
                text-align: right;
                padding-right: 2px;
            }
            .delete {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Manage Uploads</h1>
        <form id=".form-manage-uploads">
            <table id="table-writer-uploads" >                
                <tr>
                    <th>Delete</th><th>TItle</th><th>Type</th><th>Form</th><th>Genre</th><th>Length</th><th>PDF</th><th>Save</th>                
                </tr>
                <tr class="tr-clone" >
                    <td><img class="delete" src="img/icons/delete.png" alt="delete" /> </td>
                    <td><input class="title" name="title" placeholder="Title" autofocus="true" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <select class="work-type" name="work-type">
                            <option value="1">Fiction</option>
                            <option value="2">Non-Fiction</option>       
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-type" name="form-type">
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select class="genre" name="genre">
                        </select>            
                    </td>
                    <td><input class="nbr-pages" name="nbrPages" required placeholder="Pages" /></td>
                    <td><a href="" class="synopsis" target="_blank">Synopsis/Query Letter</a></td>
                    <td class="id"><input type="hidden" /></td>
                    <td><button class="save">Save</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input class="current-id" type="hidden" />

        </form>
        <script src="js/common.js"></script>
        <script src="js/manage-uploads.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if u can make a fiddle or something like demo, it will  be easy to find a solution

Comment: I have included a jsfiddle, but it works correctly. Does that provide any clues?

Comment: <script src="js/manage-uploads.js"></script> is missing your fiddle, does that do something with your form fields?

Comment: is you inputs have disabled attribute? inspect and check

Comment: @NoppeyI should remove those references. They do not come into play.

Comment: @K. Torres. I checked carefully for any disabled properties. I also tried adding a z-index: 100.

Comment: what u see? no disabled attribute?

Comment: I checked using JavaScript - disabled was false.

Comment: I can see few errors on your code here: 1) you forgot to open the <style> tag. 2) you have a weird dot inside your id: form id=".form-manage-uploads". It might help

Comment: I see no form fields disabled in your fiddle.

Comment: this doesn't appear to have anything to do with angularjs, and the fiddle that is posted to reproduce the issue doesn't exhibit the behavior described.  Also, the "answer" supplied suggests a jQuery style solution, which even further confuses the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem in an SO answer whose question was more cogent than mine. The trick is to handle the document rather than the button and include the class within the even:

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete", function (e) {
     ...
});
```